# How to make android app start when phone is switched on and nothing else is allowed to run in background?

Tags: android

I want to create a simple phone lock application in android. For that i want that when the phone is switched on my application runs first and nothing else is allowed before the lock password is entered. How can i do it. I searched it on internet but didn't get any clear and simple answer... please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky thing to do and requires lot of research and effort to achive this.
One app does this is [Toddler Lock](http://www.toddlerlock.com/)

Comment: Toddler Lock does not meet the requirement of "nothing else is allowed to run in background".

Comment: At-least it meets the requirement of "nothing else is allowed before the lock password is entered. "